# Javascript time code to be inserted in php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have this javascript code to output a specific time just like the time in my pc. what i wanted now is to insert the output time to my php mysql

```
$today = '<script type="text/javascript">

    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    curr_month++;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
    document.write(curr_hour + ":" + curr_min);

    </script>';
```

and this is my php code.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("insert into tblreserve(name, date)
 values('$name','$today')");
```

it inserts the script not the time. how can i do that?

Comment: Use AJAX to send the variable to your server: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: JS is (at least in your case) client-side - it is executed in the browser. PHP is executed on the server, long before that. So it follows, JS cannot be executed in such a way as to talk to PHP. They are chronologically incompatible. What's more, both PHP and MySQL are more than capable of reporting dates - you don't need JS.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. Just simple use instead

```
$today = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

This would output the date and time in ISO format for a DateTime column in MysQL and a Date column in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an AJAX request like this (it's in jQuery as I don't know how to do javascript ;D):

```
 //your code
 var my_date = curr_hour + ":" + curr_min;
 $.post( "login.php", {date: my_date});
```

and in PHP:

```
 $today = $_POST['date'];
 $query1 = mysql_query("insert into tblreserve(name, date) values('$name','$today')");
```